# JavaScript For Loop skips some items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to remove all of the items with more than one 'o' from the itCompanies array and then print the array to console.
I'm not sure why, but when I'm splitting each item in the array to letters to check if there are more than one 'o', Google and Apple both get skipped.

```
const itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon'];
for (let i = 0; i < itCompanies.length; i++){
    let s = itCompanies[i].split('');
    let count = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < s.length; j++){
        if (s[j] == 'o' ){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 2){
        itCompanies.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(itCompanies);
```

Output

```
Array(5)
0: "Google"
1: "Apple"
2: "IBM"
3: "Oracle"
4: "Amazon"
```

Wanted Output

```
Array(5)
0: "Apple"
1: "IBM"
2: "Oracle"
3: "Amazon"
```

Comment: splice changes the index of the actual item. you need to decrement the index with the count of deleted items.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you. That seems to have worked.

Comment: @Jashuraku occurence of `o` is sequentially or any where with in `word`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to replace the O's and then compare the lengths from the original string vs the string after the replacement.

```js
const itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon'];
const result = itCompanies.filter(s => s.length - s.replace(/o/g, "").length < 2);

console.log(result);
```

The splice has an effect on the indexes because you're mutating the array, you can work around this by looping in a backward direction.

```js
const itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon'];
for (let i = itCompanies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    let s = itCompanies[i].split('');
    let count = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < s.length; j++){
        if (s[j] == 'o' ){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 2){
        itCompanies.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(itCompanies);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method along with [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon'];

const res = itCompanies.filter(company => {
    return ![...company].filter((c1, i1, a) => a.some((c2, i2) => {
    if (c1 === 'o') {
        return c1 == c2 && i1 != i2
    }
  })).join('');
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice is basically removing the items dynamically, inside the for loop so the index of the items in the array also changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splicing the array, which changes the index , you could move the item, you like to keep into the place of deleted items and change the length at the end.

This approach keeps the same object reference to the array, as in the question.

```js
const
    itCompanies = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon'];

let i = 0, j = 0;
    
while (i < itCompanies.length) {
    if (!(itCompanies[i].match(/o/g)?.length > 1)) {
        itCompanies[j] = itCompanies[i];
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

itCompanies.length = j;

console.log(itCompanies);
```